# Registering eddystone beacon without OAuth Playground

Tags: java, oauth, eddystone

I have been using the Eddystone platform for a few months now, and things are working well. However, when registering new beacons, I am finding myself needing to open Google's OAuth 2.0 Playground and all the steps associated with it in order to send a PUT request that contains my new base64-encoded Eddystone-UID.

Is there any way to register beacons with Eddystone without having to use the OAuth 2.0 Playground? I would like to build a standalone desktop Java application that automates this process, so any Java tips would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Google's APIs to do an OAuth 2.0 sign in and then make the web service calls to the Proximity Beacon API.  The key part is setting up OAuth 2.0 on your Java client.  These two documents might help:

[Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)

[API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2)

Once you have an OAuth token, you can call the APIs as described below.  You may have already done this if you are using the playground.

[Getting Started with the Proximity Beacon API](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/get-started)

[Proximity Beacon API Overview](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/guides)

Comment: David, your restless dedication to answering questions like these gives me hope for the future of the Internet of Things. Thank you. I'll mark this as correct after I sift through the documentation and make sure that I have everything I need.